# How run node.js server with React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, localhost

I am trying implement my node.js server with React. I already configure webpack with react but I dont know how I can start it wit my server.Is it possible without using express.js?
Now it is just render index.html without other pages which exist in react.
Thank you!

Webpack.config

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "main.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html", 
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env','@babel/preset-react'],
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

server.js

```
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const indexFile = path.join(__dirname, "../src", "index.html");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/") {
    fs.readFile(indexFile, "utf-8", (err, content) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      res.end(content);
    });
  }
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server is running");
});
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": " webpack --mode development && node server/server.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that express is set to serve static files, e.g.:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist/build")));
```

And use sendFile instead of readFile:

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/dist/build", "index.html"));
});
```

Comment: I tried to do this without express if it's possible.Also I tried run ```path.join(__dirname, "../dist", "index.html") ``` but result the same.It is doesn't work

Comment: Oh I see, I just assumed you were using express! With just Node by itself it would be trickier for sure - have a look at this article it goes into the details with just Node: https://medium.com/@amitgupta15/minimal-http-server-in-node-js-without-framework-aede70695fc0